# Desktop computer gets stuck in restarting cycle (Win 10)

Tags: windows-10, crash, sleep, desktop, reboot

I've had this computer for a few years and a known issue with it was that if it went to sleep it would get stuck there. the fix for that was to remove the power supply and the internal battery for 10-20 seconds to fully restart it.

recently the computer has been crashing randomly and getting stuck in a restart loop or turning on to an error message "Your PC did not start correctly" with some options.

So I'm looking to answer 2 questions.

1. Does anyone know what I could do to resolve the immediate problems?
2. Has anyone experience the sleep issue and know a better resolution?

Thank you.

Comment: To confirm, this is a desktop, not laptop?  You actually removed the power supply from inside the desktop case, including disconnecting all of the internal cables?

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's a hardware issue or operating system (OS) issue by booting from an alternate OS, such as a USB flash drive with Live Linux, e.g. [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) (do not install on your HDD, just boot from the flash drive).

- If the PC can operate without crashing, shuts down correctly and reboots afterward under the other OS, then you've confirmed that the issue is due to either a HDD fault or Windows OS fault.
- Since this might be due to a failing HDD, boot from USB and make a disk image or copy all files to an external HDD.

  - *If that image or copy fails, partway through,* the HDD in the PC is failing. Keep trying to save files, and then replace the HDD.
  - *If the image succeeds* flawlessly, then reinstall the Windows 10 OS from a [Microsoft ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). You may be forced to update to Windows 10, v. 2020, if you get the ISO from MS; they've hidden older versions. Or, if you liked the alternative OS, install that in place of Windows.